# Last record of every day in a month issue

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have a strange problem with one record.
i have some rows for every day.
i select the last record of a day in entire month.

table is like this:

```
|name |surname|date_in            |
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-01 00:12:12
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-01 00:14:12
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-01 00:16:12
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-01 00:18:12
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-01 00:22:12
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-02 00:12:12
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-02 00:14:12
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-02 00:16:12
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-02 00:18:12
|mario|rossi  |2016-01-02 00:22:12
```

my query is like this:

```
 SELECT name,surname,date_in
 FROM table
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT MAX(date_in) AS maxim FROM table
           GROUP BY date(date_in)
    ) tableformax
    on table.date_in = tableformax.maxim
    WHERE 
    date_in > 2016-01-01 AND date_in < 2016-01-30
```

I get correctly the last row of every day but the query ignore the 2016-01-07.

If i use MIN i get all day

Any Idea?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Don't you need to have tics around your dates?  is date_in being compared against 2016-01-10 doing math 2005?  Show a (or a few) records with this date of 2016-01-07

Comment: I inserted some records

Comment: There isnt `2016-01-07` on your data. Please be specific on what result you current get, and what result you want

Comment: yes there is. i have not written all data in the questione but in real db there is !

Comment: See previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT name,surname, date(date_in) date_in_date, max(date_in) date_in_max
FROM table
WHERE date(date_in) >= '2016-01-01' and date(date_in) <= '2016-01-31'
group by date(date_in);

Try the following query and I believe that it is a monthly range.